# I am trying to get a code that will copy data from non-congruent cells in one workbook/sheet & transpose it to the next blank line on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at coding, about 3 weeks in, and I have hit a snag in my coding. I have this so far, but get an error on my 'set copy_to' line as well as how to set it to transpose the non-congruent cells to the range I want after it moves to the next blank row.

I need 4 cells from the 1st workbook pasted into the next blank row on the 2nd workbook starting on column A-D in this specific order K33(A), A36(B), G3(C) & G53(D).

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub copy_wb()

Dim copy_from As Range
Dim copy_to As Range

Set copy_from = Workbooks("FNOL Notes Doc Tool").Worksheets("CSR Notes").Range("K33,A36,G32,G53")
Set copy_to = Workbooks("Locate Form").Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

copy_from.Copy Destination:=copy_to
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If the "Locate Form" workbook is an existing workbook, not created during this session, you need to include the file extension in its name like "Locate Form.xlsx"

Comment: I added that in with the code provided by Alok and I think it will work so thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub copy_wb()

Dim copy_from As Range
Dim copy_to As Range
Dim r as range

Set copy_from = Workbooks("FNOL Notes Doc Tool").Worksheets("CSR Notes").Range("K33,A36,G32,G53")
Set copy_to = Workbooks("Locate Form").Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


 For Each r In copy_from.Areas
        r.Copy copy_to
        Set copy_to = copy_to.Offset(, 1)
 Next r

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```